# How to record the time of data entry in firebase using swift

Tags: database, swift, time, firebase

what I am looking to do here is when a new entry is posted to firebase, record the time of this entry. For example placing a shopping order and recording the time the order was placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pre-defined constant that you can use in Swift. Luckily creating the constant map is not much more difficult in swift.

From the [Firebase documentation on handling latency](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-latency):

```
var userLastOnlineRef = Firebase(url:"https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/users/joe/lastOnline")
userLastOnlineRef.onDisconnectSetValue([".sv": "timestamp"])
```